# Does Free Pascal have a way to implement SHA256 or SHA512?

Tags: freepascal, sha256, sha512

In the Free Pascal libraries there's a hash library that enables use of MD5 and SHA1 hashing algorithms (http://wiki.freepascal.org/hash). But what if I wanted to use a higher one, such as SHA256 or SHA512? Could I achieve this using Free Pascal? Searching the FP Wiki retunrs zero hits for SHA256\SHA512.

Comment: I didn't mean "Does it have the computational ability to do such hashing" - I realise if it can calculate MD5 or SHA1 it can compute larger numbers. What I meant was, is there a function or series of functions written within FP that can enable me to do this as I can't find any? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google codesearch I found several units that implement it in pascal.

Query: [sha256 | sha512 lang:pascal](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=sha256+|+sha512&as_lang=pascal)

One of the [sources](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#NIlGDWgVUQE/trunk/src/sha.pas&q=sha256%20%7C%20sha512%20lang%3apascal&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) is from [Double Commander](http://doublecmd.sourceforge.net/), which is a norton/total commander clone that's developed with FreePascal and Lazarus, so there you go.

Comment: The FPC included ones are endianess and 64-bit clean.

Comment: Thanks - that is helpful. I also discovered componnents written by the developer of FreeOTFE called SDeanComponents - http://www.sdean12.org/

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions (say 2 years or so), there is a package "hash" with units "sha1" and "md5" that implement some basic hashes and checksums

If you need more, most people use DCPCrypt as it is easily [converted](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource)

http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt

At least I see regularly posts on the lists that people are using it

Comment: I use FPC's md5 (using a DLL) even in Delphi because it is much faster than Delphi's.  FPC's in Pascal, but with ROR/ROL intrinsic.

Answer (score 1):

For other hashes I use "Delphi Encryption Compendium (DEC) 5.2". I don't know if it works with FPC, but you should try. There is `THash_SHA512` and `THash_SHA256`.
Download it from: http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=519#939342